# MiKTeX can't switch to administration mode, error while checking updates, and error downloading package

Tags: miktex

Usually I install packages from MiKTeX package manager. There was no issue before, whenever I opened MiKTeX console, it always asked me whether to switch administrator mode or user mode. But today when I opened the MiKTeX console, it said "A MiKTeX setup issue has been detected" like [this](https://ibb.co/bP9bBjh).

I tried to check for updates but error has occurred. Then I tried to install a random package but the dialog box said "The remote package repository is corrupted. You have to choose another repository".
[link image description here](https://ibb.co/dGTwMZg).

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You can select the package repository from MiKTeX Settings (click on the `change…` button for that).

Comment: I get the setup issue warning every time I start the console, even if I update packages and immediately run it again.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I also have the same problem. And I add that I can not select not even the repository where I want to download the packages.